# Set BOOL value error at ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c

Yesterday I got an error message in my app, it was on ios7.1 when I use KVC to set the value to BOOL type, the data source is @"0", and I get those error message

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString
>   charValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa2030'

It was ok in ios8 and later, is the bool have some diffent in `armv7` and `armv7s` or the different with BOOL ?

Comment: I don't see how that code would have ever worked, unless the pointer to a string constant was simply being cast to BOOL, and you were lucky that it never set the wrong value.

Comment: show your code where you added the bool value to array,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I didn't add the bool to array, it only a property in class , the code is only    [self setValue:@"0" forKey:@"_boolValue"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

if you set the bool value use `NSNumber numberWithBool` for store, for example

change this

```
[self setValue:@NO forKey:@"_boolValue"]
```

into

```
[self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"_boolValue"];
```

Comment: yes, i know it works, but i want know the why it work well in ios8

Comment: may be the version control it occur ,

Comment: OK, i gonna to see the doc to get some info

Comment: ok , if anything you find inform me it is useful for others ]

Comment: why you given thedownvote , if you give the reason I modify my answer

Answer (score 0):

the BOOL define is change at 64-bit,so i got some explain at this blog,Click here https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bools-sharp-corners/  i think it maybe help others